# Why does the Linux kernel contain duplicate code?

Tags: c, linux, dry, clean-architecture

So I was looking around the Linux kernel (v 2.6.9) and I found that the boot sector code for i386 and x86_64 architectures have idential code. But isn't the golden rule of programming to keep your code DRY (do not write duplicate code)? So why the Linux maintainers didn't just re-use this file instead of copy - pasting it? I'm trying to learn good and clean code and this confused me. I mean if 2 architectures share the same boot code - just reuse it?

In the Linux source code these two files are exactly the same.

`/arch/i386/boot/bootsect.S` and `/arch/x86_64/boot/bootsect.S`

```
/*
 *  bootsect.S      Copyright (C) 1991, 1992 Linus Torvalds
 *
 *  modified by Drew Eckhardt
 *  modified by Bruce Evans (bde)
 *  modified by Chris Noe (May 1999) (as86 -> gas)
 *  gutted by H. Peter Anvin (Jan 2003)
 *
 * BIG FAT NOTE: We're in real mode using 64k segments.  Therefore segment
 * addresses must be multiplied by 16 to obtain their respective linear
 * addresses. To avoid confusion, linear addresses are written using leading
 * hex while segment addresses are written as segment:offset.
 *
 */

#include <asm/boot.h>

SETUPSECTS  = 4         /* default nr of setup-sectors */
BOOTSEG     = 0x07C0        /* original address of boot-sector */
INITSEG     = DEF_INITSEG       /* we move boot here - out of the way */
SETUPSEG    = DEF_SETUPSEG      /* setup starts here */
SYSSEG      = DEF_SYSSEG        /* system loaded at 0x10000 (65536) */
SYSSIZE     = DEF_SYSSIZE       /* system size: # of 16-byte clicks */
                    /* to be loaded */
ROOT_DEV    = 0             /* ROOT_DEV is now written by "build" */
SWAP_DEV    = 0         /* SWAP_DEV is now written by "build" */

#ifndef SVGA_MODE
#define SVGA_MODE ASK_VGA
#endif

#ifndef RAMDISK
#define RAMDISK 0
#endif

#ifndef ROOT_RDONLY
#define ROOT_RDONLY 1
#endif

.code16
.text

.global _start
_start:

    # Normalize the start address
    jmpl    $BOOTSEG, $start2

start2:
    movw    %cs, %ax
    movw    %ax, %ds
    movw    %ax, %es
    movw    %ax, %ss
    movw    $0x7c00, %sp
    sti
    cld

    movw    $bugger_off_msg, %si

msg_loop:
    lodsb
    andb    %al, %al
    jz  die
    movb    $0xe, %ah
    movw    $7, %bx
    int $0x10
    jmp msg_loop

die:
    # Allow the user to press a key, then reboot
    xorw    %ax, %ax
    int $0x16
    int $0x19
    
    # int 0x19 should never return.  In case it does anyway,
    # invoke the BIOS reset code...
    ljmp    $0xf000,$0xfff0


bugger_off_msg:
    .ascii  "Direct booting from floppy is no longer supported.\r\n"
    .ascii  "Please use a boot loader program instead.\r\n"
    .ascii  "\n"
    .ascii  "Remove disk and press any key to reboot . . .\r\n"
    .byte   0


    # Kernel attributes; used by setup

    .org 497
setup_sects:    .byte SETUPSECTS
root_flags: .word ROOT_RDONLY
syssize:    .word SYSSIZE
swap_dev:   .word SWAP_DEV
ram_size:   .word RAMDISK
vid_mode:   .word SVGA_MODE
root_dev:   .word ROOT_DEV
boot_flag:  .word 0xAA55
```

Comment: Look at the /arch/x86_64/boot directory for the 2.6.23 kernel and you will see that the Makefile there just builds the code from the /arch/i386/boot directory. In the 2.6.24 kernel, the /arch/i386 and /arch/x86_64 directories were combined into /arch/x86.

Comment: The Linux kernel is continuously in flux, and you seem to have found a great example of this.

Comment: Re “the golden rule of programming”: It is a guideline, not a rule, and it is not a golden rule, and it is not the golden rule.

Comment: The golden rule is to teach beginning programmers things like: don't use `goto`, don't use `eval`, don't roll your own crypto, etc. More experienced programmers will know the exceptions to the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit x86 (i386) and 64-bit x86 (x86-64) do indeed have some commonalities, e.g. booting to exactly the same environment, and x86 processor in legacy 16-bit real mode.

The duplication between those two did not go unnoticed by the kernel developers either, see e.g. this LWN article (from 2007): [i386 and x86_64: back together?](https://lwn.net/Articles/243704/). (2.6.9 appears to be from around 2004, so is by now over 16 years old.)

@IanAbbott mentions in a comment that the joining of those two into `/arch/x86` eventually happened by 2.6.24 (which was released in January 2008, so about 13 years ago).